# Cardinality of infinite towers of Alephs - can tower be more than countable?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, ordinal-numbers, cardinal-arithmetic

Lets define function T as
$$T(0) = \aleph_0$$
$$T(1) = \aleph_{\aleph_0}$$
$$T(2) = \aleph_{\aleph_{\aleph_0}}$$
etc

No finite tower of alephs can reach the first inaccessible cardinal

My questions are:

1. Can we 'feed' infinite ordinal numbers as a parameter to function T? I read somewhere - it was about the inaccessible cardinals - that the size of the tower is countable, but is it just a limitation of the first order ZFC with finitely-sized formulas? Can generalized function T() be expressed in, say, second order ZFC?
2. So if there is nothing wrong with that definition of T, what is relative size of, say,
   $$T(\omega+1)$$
   $$T(\omega^2)$$
   $$T(2^{\aleph_0})$$
   Are they still below the first inaccessible cardinal?
3. Obviously, it leads to the last question: How far can we go with it, where is the fixed point of T relative to the hierarchy of the cardinals?

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear how you would extent $T$ nontrivially to infinite ordinals - if you let $T(\omega)$ be the limit of $T(n),n<\omega$, and try to define $T(\omega+1)$ as $\aleph_{T(\omega)}$, then you will find $T(\omega+1)=T(\omega)$, and by this process you will find $T(\alpha)=T(\omega)$ for all $\alpha\geq\omega$. Do you have some different definition in mind?

Comment: @Wojowu I suppose one choice could be $T(\omega+1)=\aleph_{T(\omega)+1}$? Of course, I do not know whether this is what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @Wokowu I dont think about any exact definition, I am just trying to understand why there is such limitation. Any ideas are welcome.

So what you are saying is that adding one more aleph doesn't change a height of a tower. $1+\omega = \omega$. But with ordinals we can go beyond $\epsilon_0$ by building higher tower of $\omega$ : $\epsilon_0^{\epsilon_0^{\epsilon_0}}$. Can we do the same with $\aleph_0$ ?

Anyway, what if the tower is the size of continuum?

Comment: Another thought, isn't the first inaccessible cardinal a limit of all towers, so $\theta_0 = T(\omega)$ ? In such case $T(\omega+1) = \theta_{\aleph_0}$ ?

Comment: Similar things have been asked elsewhere, eg https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2689417/fixed-point-union-of-aleph-0-aleph-aleph-0-aleph-aleph-aleph-0-do and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747465/question-about-aleph-fixed-point . See also https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number#Aleph-%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000035-QINU%60%22'%7F_for_general_%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-00000036-QINU%60%22'%7F

Comment: I'm not aware of any general definitions of "tower of length [whatever]" which would let $\epsilon_0^{\epsilon_0^{\epsilon_0}}$, do you know of a definition which achieves that? I don't think the problem is with limitation of ZFC to only having finite formulas or being first-order, it's about it being unclear what such a tower should mean. To address your last question: I'm not sure what $\theta_0$ is, but $T(\omega)$, the limit of $T(n),n<\omega$, is way smaller than the first inaccessible.

Comment: @Wojowu Thank you, you're right, of course, it is not possible for any tower to reach first inaccessible. But $T(\omega)$ can't be the highest tower as well, because $T(\omega)^{+}$ is bigger, so there should be many cardinalities between $T(\omega)$ and the first inaccessible - probably, these cardinalities can be coded by the parameter of T greater than $\omega$

Comment: @Wojowu for the tower of epsilons, I found it in Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_numbers_(mathematics)

Comment: RE first comment, well of course $T(\omega)^+$ is a larger *cardinal*, but to claim it is a larger *tower* you would need to define what counts as a tower, which gets us back to square one. RE second comment, the Wikipedia article you link at no point mentions any towers, let alone ones of transfinite length.

Comment: An inaccessible can’t have the same cofinality as any ordinal smaller than it, and these things you’re defining have smaller cofinalities by definition. I don’t think you can reach any really big ordinals this way.

Comment: @Wojowu Wiki claims that $\epsilon_1$ can be defined as infinite tower of $\epsilon_0$, but $\epsilon_0$ is an infinite tower of $\omega$, so repeating $\omega$ exponentiation $\omega$ times we get $\epsilon_0$, but repeating it more we get $\epsilon_1$

Comment: @AlecRhea yes, so there is a huge gap between $T(\omega)$ and first inaccesible.

Comment: @tzimie "Wiki claims that $\epsilon_1$ can be defined as infinite tower of $\epsilon_0$" Not quite - we *also* need to throw in some "$+1$"s to make it work. Specifically, $$\epsilon_1=\sup\{\epsilon_0+1, \omega^{\epsilon_0+1}, \omega^{\omega^{\epsilon_0+1}}, ...\}.$$ That "$+1$" might look minor but it makes a huge difference. (See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3669920/28111).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Transfinite towers" often run into the problem of **termination**: when $F$ is a "nice" function on ordinals (= monotonic, nondecreasing, and continuous), we get $$F(\sup\{F^n(0): n\in\omega\}=\sup\{F^n(0):n\in\omega\}.$$ That is, the "iterating $F$" tower stops at level $\omega$. Moreover, if the sequence $(F^n(0))_{n\in\omega}$ was strictly increasing, then this least fixed point of $F$ will have cofinality $\omega$ and so not be inaccessible.

The "$+1$"-versions of such towers avoid this termination issue, at the cost of being a bit stranger. For example, consider the function on ordinals defined recursively as follows:

- $S(0)=\omega+1$.
- $S(\alpha+1)=\omega_{S(\alpha)}+1$.
- $S(\lambda)=\sup\{S(\alpha): \alpha<\lambda\}+1.$

This function never "stops," in the sense that we always have $S(\alpha)<S(\alpha+1)$. We can then try to "strip off" the added $+1$s by taking cardinalities: let $$\hat{T}(\alpha)=\vert S(\alpha)\vert.$$ This $\hat{T}$ function isn't quite your $T$ but it's fairly similar: it begins $$\hat{T}(0)=\aleph_0, \quad\hat{T}(1)=\vert \omega_{\omega+1}+1\vert=\aleph_{\omega+1},\quad\hat{T}(2)=\vert\omega_{\omega_{\omega+1}+1}+1\vert=\aleph_{\omega_{\omega+1}+1}, \quad...$$ In particular, we get $$T(0)=\hat{T}(0)<T(1)<\hat{T}(1)<T(2)<\hat{T}(2)<...$$ (Note that $\aleph$s should not be used in subscripts to $\aleph$ numbers.)

The functions $S$ and $\hat{T}$ are provably total in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, and - being "non-silly" (e.g. not having an inaccessible somehow baked in if possible) - don't reach up to an inaccessible before we feed in an inaccessible at the outset. Specifically, the least $\alpha$ such that $S(\alpha)$ is $\ge$ the least inaccessible (in fact, equal to the least inaccessible $+1$) is the least inaccessible itself.

---

But from the end of your question, it sounds like this isn't quite what you want; rather, you want an iterative process which *does* have a fixed point, but whose least fixed point is extremely large (e.g. plausibly an inaccessible cardinal). This is going to be tricky: since $\mathsf{ZFC}$ doesn't prove that inaccessibles exist (unless it's inconsistent in the first place!), such a function has to have some aspect which is independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$.

Here's one example of such a function, albeit in a modified setting. Working in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "There is a proper class of inaccessible cardinals," and restricting to uncountable cardinals for simplicity, let $C(\kappa)$ be the smallest inaccessible cardinal $\lambda$ such that every unsatisfiable $\mathcal{L}_{\kappa,\kappa}$-theory of size at most $\kappa$ has an unsatisfiable subset of size $<\lambda$. Obviously $C(\kappa)\le\kappa^+$; fixed points for $C$ are exactly the **weakly compact** cardinals, whose existence is independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "There is a proper class of inaccessible cardinals."

But the function $C$ itself isn't really very interesting, and in fact the property of being a $C$-fixed point is more naturally expressed without reference to $C$ itself (namely, "is inaccessible and has the weak compactness property"). In general, large cardinals are rarely best thought of as least fixed points.